# Unable to start X, load amdgpu driver, after graphics card upgrade

Tags: x11, amdgpu

I recently upgraded my graphics card to a Radeon RX 6600 (from R9 290x) and I've been unable to get the desktop to load properly since then. I can get it to start by blowing-away the xorg.conf file but then the amdgpu driver fails to load. Initially, I was running the older radeon driver but I've since removed that and upgraded to amdgpu. The information below is without a desktop config loaded.

`cat /etc/os-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
```

`lshw -c video`

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe500000-fe5fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

`X -config /root/xorg.conf.new`

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Debian
Current Operating System: Linux Office 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.10.0-21-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/Office--vg-root ro radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1
Build Date: 01 February 2023  02:11:18PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.11-1+deb11u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Mar  5 14:18:09 2023
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(2): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(3): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(4): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(5): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(6): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(7): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(8): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(9): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(10): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(11): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(12): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(13): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(14): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(15): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(16): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(17): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(18): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(19): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(20): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(21): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(22): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(23): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(II) AMDGPU(24): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

`grep 'EE\|amd' /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[  5049.627] Current Operating System: Linux Office 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64
[  5049.627] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.10.0-21-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/Office--vg-root ro radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  5049.636] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[  5049.637] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  5049.637] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  5049.638] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[  5049.638] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[  5049.638] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  5049.638] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

`sudo apt list --upgradable`

```
Listing... Done
```

`glxinfo | grep -i 'amd\|OpenGL'`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.3.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_texture_texture4, 
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.3.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

`lsmod | grep amdgpu`

```
amdgpu               6713344  0
gpu_sched              49152  1 amdgpu
ttm                   114688  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        278528  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
drm                   626688  4 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
```

`sudo lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] (rev c7)
    Subsystem: XFX Limited Navi 23
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
root@Office:/etc/X11#
```

`dpkg --get-selections | grep xserver-xorg-video`

```
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu           install
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev            install
xserver-xorg-video-intel            install
xserver-xorg-video-modesetting          deinstall
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau          install
xserver-xorg-video-qxl              install
xserver-xorg-video-vesa             install
xserver-xorg-video-vmware           install
```

`sudo systemctl status display-manager`

```
gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-03-05 13:55:32 EST; 2h 0min ago
    Process: 1513 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1528 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18954)
     Memory: 6.3M
        CPU: 309ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─1528 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Mar 05 14:18:32 Office gdm3[1528]: Gdm: Child process -7927 was already dead.
Mar 05 15:14:15 Office gdm3[1528]: GLib: Source ID 262 was not found when attempting to remove it
Mar 05 15:14:16 Office gdm-launch-environment][13938]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user Debian-gdm(u>
Mar 05 15:14:16 Office gdm-launch-environment][13938]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user Debian-gdm
Mar 05 15:14:16 Office gdm3[1528]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Mar 05 15:14:16 Office gdm3[1528]: Gdm: Child process -14009 was already dead.
Mar 05 15:14:16 Office gdm3[1528]: Gdm: Child process -14009 was already dead.
Mar 05 15:14:16 Office gdm-launch-environment][14060]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user Debian-gdm(u>
Mar 05 15:14:29 Office gdm3[1528]: GLib: Source ID 284 was not found when attempting to remove it
Mar 05 15:14:39 Office gdm3[1528]: Gdm: Child process -14097 was already dead.
```

Xorg log file when booting with a configuration file:

```
are: [    34.589] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.589] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[    34.594] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.594]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 19.1.0
[    34.594]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.594]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
    All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(2): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(3): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(4): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(5): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(6): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(7): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.594] (II) AMDGPU(8): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(9): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(10): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(11): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(12): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(13): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(14): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(15): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(16): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(17): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(18): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(19): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(20): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(21): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(22): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(23): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (II) AMDGPU(24): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    34.595] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.595] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.595] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.595] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.595] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.595] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.595] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.595] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.595] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.595] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.595] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.595] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    34.596] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    34.596] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[    34.596] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    34.596] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    34.596] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
```

Any idea what's causing the **(EE) no screens found(EE)** errors?

Thanks